# PDF Download option not working in pdf.js used in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am displaying a PDF that already embedded in the app's resources. I am using pdf.js. Displaying method is working very well. My problem is I cannot download that PDF to the local storage. Both iOS and Android. Download button not working. I used this example :

https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf

Comment: Can you share us your codes about how did you implement the downloading process? This example is about displaying a PDF file.

Comment: This pdf.js has a download option inbuilt. I tried to download using it. I didn't wrote any code specifically for downloading

Comment: Well, I find it. I will update you if I find anything.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT ok, thankz mate

Comment: Any update on this?